# Moving some database logic to its own helper module in Flask-Sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to separate some of my database logic into its own helper module. This is because I have several routes that perform the same database functions, and I don't want to keep repeating the same code. I'm a bit confused on the db session scopes.

From the [SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session_basics.html) docs:

> Some web frameworks include infrastructure to assist in the task of aligning the lifespan of a Session with that of a web request. This includes products such as Flask-SQLAlchemy, for usage in conjunction with the Flask web framework...

I think this means my db session scope is contained within a particular route since I'm using Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy, so I came up with the following:

**init.py**

```
app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

**routes.py**

```
from init import db

@app.route('/one')
def one():
    form = MyForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        myhelper.saveStuff1(form.stuff1.data)
        myhelper.saveStuff2(form.stuff2.data)

        db.session.commit()
    return render_template(...)

@app.route('/two')
def two():
    form = MyForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        myhelper.saveStuff1(form.stuff1.data)
        myhelper.saveStuff2(form.stuff2.data)
        myhelper.saveStuff3(form.stuff3.data)

        db.session.commit()
    return render_template(...)
```

**myhelper.py**

```
from init import db

# Add new Item
def saveStuff1(formdata):
    db.session.add(Item(name=formdata))

# Update Item
def saveStuff2(formdata):
    item = Item.query.filter_by(name=formdata).first()
    item.description = 'default'
    db.session.add(item)

# etc...
```

Would this be the correct way for structuring my helpers? I'm worried that `from init import db` will cause problems with scoping since it's imported in both files, or if this overall code pattern will cause other problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLAlchemy's session scope is not related to Python's variable scope.  So no, importing `db` in multiple places as you've shown won't cause problems.  Regarding the session scope, Flask-SQLAlchemy takes care of that for you, so you can ignore (or not worry about) the discussion of scope in the SQLAlchemy docs.